# Internal Server error 500 : No file specified in the request body

Tags: c#, http-post, console-application

I am using and API that accepts an image file and returns a JSON string as a response on console C# application. **I am sending the image to the API using HTTP POST method and I keep getting an error message from the server saying: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. No specified file in the request body**, the code I wrote so far:

```
  public static void HttpUploadFile(string url, string file, string paramName, string contentType)
    {
      string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
      byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        wr.Method = "POST";
        wr.KeepAlive = true;
        wr.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; 
        Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();  
        string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";
        string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, paramName, file, contentType);

        byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
        rs.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length-1);

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        fileStream.Close();

        byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
        rs.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);
        rs.Close();

        WebResponse wresp = null;
        try
        {
            wresp = wr.GetResponse();
            Stream stream2 = wresp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);
           Console.WriteLine(string.Format("File uploaded, server response is: {0}", reader2.ReadToEnd()));
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Error uploading file  "+ ex);

            WebResponse errResp = ex.Response;
            Console.ReadKey();

            using (Stream respStream = errResp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream);
                string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(text);
                Console.ReadKey();

            }

            if (wresp != null)
            {
                wresp.Close();
                wresp = null;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            wr = null;
        }
    }
```

I am sending to this method the following parameters from the main:

```
  HttpUploadFile(URL,
             @"SomeImage.jpg", "file", "image/jpg");
```

The Image location is in the solution's directory: Project/bin/debug.

**The exact error message :** 
Error uploading file  System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
{"code": 500,"error": "Invalid Request - No file specified in the request body"}

I looked all over the internet for similar issues but couldn't find a solution for the problem, does anyone know what might be the error? or have any assumptions?

Comment: Seems we should know what API this is or we know the server implementation. I can implement a server that always responds like this, no matter what you send.

Comment: You should monitor the network trafic to check if the file is being sent and ignored. You could be not sending the file or sending the file but at server side it could be ignored

Comment: @bradbury9 do you know how can I check the traffic and keep and track the file?

Comment: @Mustafa there are many free/opensource tools. "Whireshark" is widely used, Microsoft has another one called "Microsoft Network Monitor"